# Wooocommerce order "on-sale first" products inside shop and archives

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i need to alter **the default woocommerce filter** by setting up the "on sale" products as first. The loop must contain also the not on sale, but all is ordered by on sale first.

I tried using **pre_get_posts** but i find the way only to filter the products (for ex display only the on sale product), not **reorder** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, here the solution, hope is useful for other people.

```
  /**
 * @param $q
 * Reorder products on sale first on default shop filter.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function evolve_on_sale_reorder_query( $q ) {
    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => '_sale_price',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'     => '_sale_price',
                    'value'   => '',
                    'compare' => "="
                    // 'value'=>array(''),
                    // 'compare' => 'IN'
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => '_sale_price',
                    'value'   => 0,
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                )
            ),
        );

        $q->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ) );
    }

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );


}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'evolve_on_sale_reorder_query' );
```